# Delete a List item

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have here a class and a List for my Purchasers:

```
public class Purchaser
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool Paid { get; set; }
}

List<Purchaser> Purchasers = new List<Purchaser>();
```

I also have a code to add new purchasers by cathing the text from one textbox and adding it to the Purchaser List and to my listbox **listDOF**:

```
if(box_AddPerson.TextLength != 0)
{
    Purchaser purchaser = new Purchaser();
    purchaser.Name = caixa_AddJog.Text;
    purchaser.Paid = true;
    listDOF.Items.Add(purchaser.Name);
    Purchasers.Add(purchaser);
 }
```

This code works well, the purchaser is added to the Purchaser List and also to my listbox.
Now what I need is be able to remove one purchaser by the listbox. I tried this, in the click event of one button:

```
if(listDOF.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
{
    Purchaser purchaser = new Purchaser();
    Purchasers.Remove(purchaser);
    listDOF.Items.Remove(listDOF.SelectedItem);
}
```

This works well for removing the selected purchaser from the listbox. But how to also remove him from the Purchaser List?
Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `Data bound items` of `ListBox`

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
Purchasers.Add(new Purchaser { Name = "test", Paid = true });
Purchasers.Add(new Purchaser { Name = "test1", Paid = true });
Purchasers.Add(new Purchaser { Name = "test2", Paid = true });
bs.DataSource = Purchasers;
listBox1.DataSource = bs;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Then this how to remove.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bs.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Ohh man how I did not think about it? So easy... Yes, this worked great! Thank you, friend! A hug!

Comment: @Hypister you dont even need to create a list,you can just add items to the bindingsource directly,the first item added will dictate the type of the internal list managed by the bindingsource.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing . You create a new `purchaser` and remove it?!

What you want to do is find the item you want to remove (the selected one), and then remove that item from the list you want to remove it from.

something along:

```
var item_to_remove = // selected index
listDOF.Items.Remove(item_to_remove);
```

Comment: I have the purchasers in the listbox and also in the Purchaser List.
I have a button to remove the purchasers that I want. My code removes the selected purchaser from the listbox, but I need to know how to remove the selected purchaser in the Purchaser List too.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `listDOF.Items.RemoveAt(item_to_remove)`?

Comment: @sukhoi191 you can either remove the object that matches, or use remove at index. Whichever tickles your fancy :)

Comment: spajce showed me the solution. Thanks all who tried to help! :)

Comment: @Noctis First there was `Removed`, probably just a typo, but it could mislead someone who never used it before :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to remove the item:

```
  if ( listDOF.SelectedItems.Count != 0 )
  {
    Purchasers.RemoveAll( x => x.Name.Equals( listDOF.SelectedItem ) );
    listDOF.Items.Remove( listDOF.SelectedItem );
  }
```

Comment: I've already get the solution, but this also may be useful! Thanks!